# Should we merge the two tags [bpm] and [bpms]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I went through the list of 50 questions tagged with [bpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpms) and I think we could merge them with [bpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpm). I suggest to keep [bpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpms) and ditch [bpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpm). Reasons:

- The acronym bpm is ambiguous because it could stand for "business process *management*", "business process *modeling*" or (as two of the fifty questions and the comment below attest) for "beats per minute".
- Most of the questions in both lists deal with process modeling *software* or, in other words, "business process management systems"

In addition, I suggest to make [bpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpm) a synonym of [bpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpms) as suggested in the comments below.

Comment: And here I was thinking "beats per minute" and wondering how that could be pluralized.

Comment: bpm is the more popular tag to use though. So if this happens then bpm should become a synonym of bpms.

Comment: @Gimby and others: In a related move, I have just created a proposal for a new community that only deals with business process modeling because I noticed that many business-related questions around process modeling are lost amongst the software-focussed questions around modeling apps in the stackexchange community. Feel free to have a look and I am looking forward to your inputs regarding the community's future ! : https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121238/business-process-modeling?referrer=IU7kc0WmXuuHw8-vDBM9aw2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the 57 questions tagged [bpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpms), and surprisingly no question was about "beats per minutes". There was one question [about a card software called PMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036244/send-a-tcp-ip-command), which I removed the tag from. I then added [bpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpms) as a synonym for [bpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpms), that is [bpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpms) (× 56) → [bpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpm) (× 596).

As mentioned before, acronyms are inherently confusing. So I renamed the tag to [business-process-management-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-process-management-system) and added both [bpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpm) and [bpms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bpms) as synonyms. Let me know if you need a different name for it.

Comment: Dear @bhargav-rao, thanks for the update on this issue ! I think your approach to avoid acronyms altogether is great ! It made me think that we could go a bit further and rename the tag to "business-process-management", which would make it include software as well as methods, notations etc. Such a more general tag would also allow us to merge the tag "business-process" into it. The latter is not a very active tag and "BP management" is probably more meaningful than just "business-process". What do you think ?l

Comment: @khalito, [business-process-management] sounds fine, I can rename it to that. [tag:business-process] seems to be a mix of questions about [tag:bpms] and [tag:bpmn], so all questions in that tag probably needs to be just retagged into one of these two other tags.

Comment: Great, let's do it this way !

Comment: The rename is done. The second part should be its own question (so that it is easier to track progress on that tag).